# RC bandpass filter using two port network parameters?

Tags: filter, band-pass

So my assignment is about exploring two port networks and the use of the 4 parameters, now one of the tasks is to design a bandpass filter with cascaded high pass and low pass filters, now I am really struggling to do this with the use of two port network parameters, anything I have tried ended with really nasty looking expressions. Is it even a good idea to use two port network parameters for such circuit ? which one of the parameter would I possibly have an easier time trying ? Only given values are the cut off frequencies.

Comment: Since s22 of 1st filter becomes source to 2nd filters s11 , it can be useful for comprehension but more difficult way to design one.  Usually low Zout of 1st and high Zin of 2nd stage is easy way to go. But first you need specs.  Pass breakpoints and stop rejection at breakpoints

Comment: After you learn the hard way , automated tools do it for you